# How to add a vertical scroll bar to a dojo select?

Tags: dojo

I’m dynamically populating a Dojo select widget, but the list seems to be abnormally long. How can I add a vertical scroll bar to it? The size attribute doesn’t work here.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a dijit.form.Select there's an attribute called maxHeight that controls the height of the dropdown.